# Django Permissions on WSL Ubuntu with Symlinked project folder

Tags: django, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, symlink

Hi I am fairly new to WSL and working in this environment.
I am trying to run a Django project within a project folder that is Symlinked within Ubuntu. The location is on C:/projects.

When I create a project I get the following error:

```
Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /mnt/c/projects/websites/vahana/manage.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.
Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /mnt/c/projects/websites/vahana/vahana/urls.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.
Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /mnt/c/projects/websites/vahana/vahana/wsgi.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.
Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /mnt/c/projects/websites/vahana/vahana/settings.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.
Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /mnt/c/projects/websites/vahana/vahana/asgi.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.
Notice: Couldn't set permission bits on /mnt/c/projects/websites/vahana/vahana/__init__.py. You're probably using an uncommon filesystem setup. No problem.
```

[Error Shown when creating a project or app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKCFA.png)

Thanks

I looked at trying to set permissions on the windows system to have full access. But I cannot resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

i tried using the sudo command before the project or app creation command and it worked.